# Failed to compile Wiley NJD v5 latex template zip downloaded from Wiley official

Tags: templates, wiley-article

1. Following the [author guideline](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/page/journal/10991239/homepage/forauthors.html), I downloaded **Wiley NJD v5** [template zip file](https://authorservices.wiley.com/asset/WileyNJDv5_Template.zip) from the official site.
2. Then, as I following the *author-guideline.pdf* inside the zip file to compile the tex file, it failed.
3. Tried Xelatex, pdflatex, latexmk, lualatex... ALL FAILED.
4. Upload the zip folder onto overleaf. Builded it. Failed.

Anything wrong with my operations?

My environment: windows 11, texlive 2023.

Comment: what does failed mean, show the error message from the log file

Comment: Could it possible that the template offfered on the official site is not compilable? Sorry, I'm not proffesional on latex. I tried my best and yet I could not make it.

Comment: The template is a complete mess

Comment: well the first step would be to remove the local listings.sty they are distributing. The next to complain to them why their class is missing so many \fi (starting from line 4740.

Comment: You tried and failed it too? Is there any possibility that I can fix it and upload to overleaf so that the others can avoid struggling with this problem?

Comment: the only way to avoid that other struggle with this too is to correct the package at the source. So complain.

Comment: Is it possible to downvote this template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template includes private copies of standard packages and standard fonts which makes very little sense, and if you use it with texlive 2023 it stops with

```
) (./listings.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty

***
*** This file requires `listings.sty' version 1.9.
*** You have a serious problem, so I'm exiting ...
***
```

If you delete the version of `listings.sty`  in the template, the supplied `wileyNJDv5_AMA.tex` does run without error with both pdflatex and lualatex
but with several warnings and ending with

```
(\end occurred when \iftrue on line 4824 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 4812 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 4800 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 4788 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 4776 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 4764 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 4752 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 4740 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 2 was incomplete)
```

However as a commercially supported class, it's not reasonable to debug it, I would just use it as is if they are requiring that, but complain to the publisher and ask that they provide an example document that runs without warning.

Comment: Thanks very much! I checked `listings.sty` if it is installed on my computer and wondered why is this warning poped. Just deleted it and successed compiling. You are my hero!

Answer (score 1):

I have also been plagued by this and have found the answer. It's an embarrassment to see the poor support Wiley gives for this `NJD-v5` template.

The issue with Overleaf/LaTeX editors is the version of TeX Live 2023. If you roll back to 2022, the template compiles successfully with `listings.sty`.

It is probably not wise to delete that file.

If you use Overleaf (why don't you), click 'Menu' in the top left and then change the 'TeX Live' version to 2022, the template compiles without error.

I can't speak to other LaTeX editors but hopefully a change in TeX live versions is easy to do.

[image]