Font STIX-Regular cannot be found using WileyNJDv5
I am trying to use the official Latex template WileyNJDv5 (https://authorservices.wiley.com/asset/WileyNJDv5_Template.zip). Everything seems to work fine as long as I use
\documentclass[AMA,Times1COL]{WileyNJDv5}
but if I switch to
\documentclass[AMA,STIX2COL]{WileyNJDv5}
as required by my journal I get:
! Package fontspec Error: The font "STIX-Regular" cannot be found.
Same error with any engine: LuaLaTex, XeLateX...
But I installed the all STRIX fonts. They are all in -/font folder.
Thanks in advance.

Please specify which engine you are using. It seems to be either xelatex or lualatex. STIX is already included in latex not much need to manually install it. Where exactly is that font folder compared to your LaTeX file?

Note that when you are using a non-standard class (aka not on CTAN), you should always provide a link to the version you are using.

@daleif, -\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\font, the LaTex file is in documents.

Are you sure LaTeX looks for this there?

I really do not know, maybe in -\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts\opentype, I found the .otf there.

Note that the class expects the fonts to be in a subfolder named Fonts/ of the folder where your main file is. This is also the structure in the ZIP one downloads

And then it works just fine. Though the class gives a lot of \end occurred when \iftrue  warings

@daleif, thank you very much indeed, it works as you said, however nothing changes as I swap from Times1COL, to STIX1COL, STIX2COL or STIXSMALL, but I should not have two columns with STIX2COL?

What do you mean nothing changes? The font change.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701991/1090

Several things at play here

The ZIP provides the fonts in a Fonts/ subfolder. It refers to this folder afterwards, so the folder needs to be a subfolder of the folder with the main document.
The ZIP contains an old copy of listings.sty, but listings consists of several files and the ones from the LaTeX installation fails when you are trying to use an older listings.sty.
The viewer in texmaker might not like the STIX fonts.

