listings package required but not supported in template
I am getting an error when I am trying to compile a big template document.  The document loads the package lstmisc.sty, but when loaded I get a error that says this package  listings.sty version 1.10a and then it fails to run.  When I delete the line that loads in lstmisc.sty the document is not formatted correctly.  I know this isn't the most detail in the world, but has anyone see this type of error before?  The template I am using is here, it is for a Wiley journal. The problem occurs in the subfile listings.sty.

That template ships with an outdated version of listings.sty without also shipping the relevant support flies (lstmisc in this case). But that's not the only problem with that template, it also tries to load etex and use its \reserveinserts even though loading etex is aborted in "modern" LaTeX. All in all I'd suggest contacting Wiley and reporting the issues you find with their template to them. Also, if your journal accepts "Free Format submission" I suggest you use that, because their template is broken.

If you feel like adding the support files manually you can download the 1.8d version of lstmisc.sty (which matches the version of listings.sty in the template) from https://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2020/tlnet-final/archive/listings.tar.xz.

duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701991/1090
